# How to optimize this?

Tags: java, sql, optimization

So I have this piece of code to add a list of brokers to a local SQLite database as one single sql instruction.

```
public void Add(List<Broker> brokers)
{
    if(brokers == null || brokers.size() == 0)
      return;

    String sql = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " SELECT " + brokers.get(0).getId() + " AS '" + COLUMN_BROKERID + "', "+ brokers.get(0).getOfficeId() + " AS '" + COLUMN_OFFICEID +  "', '"+ brokers.get(0).getName() + "' AS '" + COLUMN_NAME +  "', "+ brokers.get(0).getSuccessRate() + " AS '" + COLUMN_SUCCESSRATE +  "'";

    for(int i=1; i<brokers.size(); i++)
    {
        sql = sql + " UNION SELECT " + brokers.get(i).getId() + ", " + brokers.get(i).getOfficeId() + ", '" + brokers.get(i).getName() + "', " + brokers.get(i).getSuccessRate();
    }

    databaseManager.ExecuteNonQuery(sql);
 }
```

But what slows this down a lot is the change in the string 'sql'. The last line, which is a call to `ExecuteNonQuery()` takes a millisecond, but the above take a lot. How can I speed this up?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: What is the `databaseManager` object? What is the `ExecuteNonQuery` method? Шо? - короче говоря

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would advice to use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to build your query String. Note that it's not thread safe; if you need that, use [`StringBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html).

It roughly looks like this:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("INSERT INTO ");
    sb.append(TABLE_NAME);
    sb.append(" SELECT ");
    sb.append(brokers.get(0).getId());
    sb.append(" AS '");
    sb.append(COLUMN_BROKERID);
```

Using 10.000 brokers, the original approach takes 13984 milliseconds on my machine. Refactoring to a `StringBuilder` narrows it to 15 or 16 milliseconds.

Next, you could try using [String formatting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29). It roughly looks like this:

```
String test = String.format("INSERT INTO %1...", TABLE_NAME);
```

Whether it performs better or not is hard to say upfront, but you can measure that and decide whether or not it increases performance.

Comment: tried it, doesn't help

Comment: Have you tried it according to the (updated) example? It yields me a 1.000 time gain...

Answer (score 2):

Don't ever use Strings to build up an SQL query.

Instead, use a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) and set the placeholders. This is both typesafe and eliminates the risk of SQL injection.

If your query has to be build programmatically due to conditions at runtime, then use @mthmulders suggestion to build the prepared statement with.

Comment: Maybe you can show how to do the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... UNION` construction using a `PreparedStatement`. I agree that generally, `PreparedStatements` are a good option, but don't (yet) see how to build this query _as a single statement_.

Comment: @mthmulders Well, you can build up the string for the PreparedStatement in the exact same way as you did with your direct statement, so that the variable unions are added to the complete string and then used in the creation of the PreparedStatement. Only drawback is, that you'd have to iterate again to set the placeholders.